# Bootstrap Matrix Carousel

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a homepage for a group company website and other pages will be linked from here.
The homepage will be matrix carousel. First slides will be horizontal and redirect to another pages like each company's webpage and next one the next news and etc[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2TDl.jpg).
Second carousel is going to be vertical and each slide will show different pages like 'news , awards, contact, etc..

Please give me an idea how can I do it in best and easy way. Is there any samples or documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **slick sldier**: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

It a has a "Center Mode" option, highlights the current slide in the middle just like the screenshot. It also has a "vertical" option, which a allows you to make your vertical slider.

I used slick slider in many other projects and it is a very stable and easily styleable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I also have something like below. The slide works horizontally having five slides and I want to add another vertical carousel to control the horizontal one. For example if the vertical carousel is 1 it runs the horizontal once and if it is 2 (next) it will run another different horizontal in the same container.

```js
(function ($) {
    // 创建构造函数
    function Slide(ele, options) {
        this.$ele = $(ele)//this. 构造函数的实例对象
        this.options = $.extend({
            speed: 1000,
            delay: 3000
        }, options)//拓展
        this.states = [
            { '&zIndex': 1, width: 120, height: 150, top: 71, left: 134, $opacity: 0.5 },
            { '&zIndex': 2, width: 130, height: 170, top: 61, left: 0, $opacity: 0.6 },
            { '&zIndex': 3, width: 170, height: 218, top: 37, left: 110, $opacity: 0.7 },
            { '&zIndex': 4, width: 224, height: 288, top: 0, left: 262, $opacity: 1 },
            { '&zIndex': 3, width: 170, height: 218, top: 37, left: 468, $opacity: 0.7 },
            { '&zIndex': 2, width: 130, height: 170, top: 61, left: 620, $opacity: 0.6 },
            { '&zIndex': 1, width: 120, height: 150, top: 71, left: 496, $opacity: 0.5 }
        ]
        this.lis = this.$ele.find('li')
        this.interval
        // 点击切换到下一张

        this.$ele.find('section:nth-child(2)').on('click', function () {
            this.stop()
            this.next()
            this.play()
        }.bind(this))
        // 点击切换到上一张
        this.$ele.find('section:nth-child(1)').on('click', function () {
            this.stop()
            this.prev()
            this.play()
        }.bind(this))
        this.move()
        // 让轮播图开始自动播放
        this.play()
    }


    Slide.prototype = {


        // 原型是一个对象，所以写成一个花括号

        // move()方法让轮播图到达states指定的状态
        // <1>当页面打开时将轮播图从中心点展开
        // <2>当轮播图已经展开时，会滚动轮播图(需要翻转states数组中的数据)
        move: function () {

            this.lis.each(function (i, el) {
                $(el)
                    .css('z-index', this.states[i]['&zIndex'])
                    .finish().animate(this.states[i], this.options.speed)
                    // .stop(true,true).animate(states[i], 1000)
                    .find('img').css('opacity', this.states[i].$opacity)
            }.bind(this))
        },
        // 让轮播图切换到下一张
        next: function () {

            this.states.unshift(this.states.pop())
            this.move()
        },
        // 让轮播图滚动到上一张
        prev: function () {

            this.states.push(this.states.shift())
            this.move()
        },
        play: function () {

            this.interval = setInterval(function () {//这个this指window
                // setInterval、setTimeOut 中的this指向window

                // states.unshift(states.pop())       //从后往前走
                // states.push(states.shift())     //从前往后走
                this.next()
            }.bind(this), this.options.delay)
        },
        // 停止自动播放
        stop: function () {
            // var _this = this
            clearInterval(this.interval)
        }

    }
    $.fn.zySlide = function (options) {
        this.each(function (i, ele) {
            new Slide(ele, options)
        })
        return this
    }
})(jQuery)
```

```css
.zy-Slide{
    font-size: 12px;
    position:relative;
    width:754px;
    height:292px;
    margin:115px auto 0;
}
.zy-Slide ul{
    position:relative;
    width:754px;
    height:292px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.zy-Slide li{
    position:absolute;
    list-style:none;
    background:#000;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    top:146px;
    left:377px;
    z-index:0;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-radius:3px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.zy-Slide li img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.zy-Slide section:nth-child(1), .zy-Slide section:nth-child(2){ position: absolute; top: 50%; width: 63px; height: 40px; margin-top: -20px; cursor: pointer; line-height: 40px; padding-left: 8px; padding-right: 10px; }
.zy-Slide section:nth-child(1){
    left:-64px;
}
.zy-Slide section:nth-child(2){
    right:-60px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- slide images-->
            <div id="Slide1" class="zy-Slide">
                <!--prev:元素中的文本通常会保留空格和换行符。而文本也会呈现为等宽字体。-->
                <section>Previous</section>
                <section>Next</section>
                <ul>
                    <!--alt + shift : 可以创建一个矩形选择区域-->
                    <li><a href="<?=base_url('home/company_detail')?>">
                    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://localhost:8012/fp/application/assets/images/_picture_01.png" /></li>
                    </a>
                    <li><img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://localhost:8012/fp/application/assets/images/2.jpg" /></li>
                    <li><img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://localhost:8012/fp/application/assets/images/3.jpg" /></li>
                    <li><img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://localhost:8012/fp/application/assets/images/4.jpg" /></li>
                    <li><img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://localhost:8012/fp/application/assets/images/5.jpg" /></li>
                    <li><img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://localhost:8012/fp/application/assets/images/6.jpg" /></li>
                    <li><img class="img-thumbnail" src="http://localhost:8012/fp/application/assets/images/7.jpg" /></li>
                </ul>
            </div> <!--slide images-->
            
            <script src="http://localhost:8012/fp/application/assets/jiaben/jquery.zySlide.js"></script>
            <script src="http://localhost:8012/fp/application/assets/jiaben/index.js"></script>
            
        </div>
    </div>
```